# Конструктор по умолчанию

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор, language-lawyer

```
class A
{
  public:
   A():a(0),b(0) {}
   explicit A(int x): a(x), b(0) {}
   A(int x, int y): a(x), b(y) {}
  private:
   int a,b;
};
```

и

```
class A
{
  public:
   explicit A(int x=0, int y=0): a(x), b(y) {}
  private:
   int a,b;
};
```

Есть ли различия? Что лучше использовать?

Comment: «Что лучше использовать» — смотря для чего.

Comment: для безопасного создания объектов класса A и их использования

Comment: Смотря что вы вкладываете в понятие «безопасное создание».

Comment: чтобы работало A a(), A b(x), A c(x,y), не было неявных приведений типа. А что ещё может быть?

Comment: если я узнаю разницу, я пойму, что мне лучше)

Comment: @закрывающий: За исключением части об использовании (которая, возможно, opinion-based, да и то я не уверен), вопрос вполне хорош. Не вижу причин для закрытия.

Comment: Нет, нельзя, поскольку при этом нарушится совместимость классов на уровне ABI (не спрашивайте, что это такое). Так или иначе, вы не можете этого добиться, не плодя новых абстракций и не используя методик сокрытия кода.

Comment: @zenden2k: Это вы на какой из вопросов отвечаете?

Comment: Я лично разницы в рамках языка не вижу навскидку.

Comment: Неявные приведения типов всё равно будут. Например: `A a((long)1, (char)2);` скомпилируется.

Comment: @zenden2k что значит "нет, нельзя" ?

Comment: @VladD в обоих случаях?

Comment: @dragonsballZ: Ну да. `explicit` защищает от того, чтобы конструктор `A` не был применён в цепочке преобразования `int -> A`. Но не в преобразовании `char -> int` для вычисления аргумента.

Comment: @VladD а, ну это ясно. Так есть ли какие-то различия между 1 и 2 случаем?

Comment: @dragonsballZ: Я сходу не вижу, может, кто-то их спецов по C++ увидит. Подождите :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти два объявления классов не эквивалентны.

Во втором объявлении класса конструктор объявлен со спецификатором функции `explicit`, а это ограничивает применение этого конструктора в различных ситуациях.

В первом же объявлении класса только конструктор преобразования объявлен со спецификатором функции `explicit`. А это означает, что другие конструкторы вы можете вызывать неявно.

То есть первое объявление предоставляет больше возможностей по использованию класса.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    explicit A( int x = 0, int y = 0  ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B
{
    B() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) {}
    explicit B( int x ): x( x ), y( 0 ) {}
    B( int x, int y ): x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

void f( const A &a ) 
{ 
    std::cout << "a.x = "  << a.x << ", a.y = " << a.y << std::endl;
}

void g( const B &b ) 
{ 
    std::cout << "b.x = "  << b.x << ", b.y = " << b.y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
//    f( {} );
//    f( { 1, 2 } );

    g( {} );
    g( { 1, 2 } );
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
b.x = 0, b.y = 0
b.x = 1, b.y = 2
```

В этой программе два вызова функции `f` закомментированы, так как если их раскомментировать, то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Другое важное отличии состоит в том, что один класс имеет всего лишь один конструктор с заданной сигнатурой, а другой класс имеет три конструктора с различными сигнатурами.

Рассмотрите еще один демонстрационный пример

```
struct A
{
    explicit A( int x = 0, int y = 0  ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B
{
    B() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) {}
    explicit B( int x ): x( x ), y( 0 ) {}
    B( int x, int y ): x( x ), y( y ) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct C
{
    //friend A::A();
    friend B::B();
};

int main()
{
}
```

Здесь в классе `C` вы можете объявить конструктор по умолчанию класса `B` в качестве друга класса `С`. Однако вы не можете сделать то же самое с конструктором по умолчанию класса `A`, чтобы объявить его другом класса `C`, так как конструктор по умолчанию в классе `A` имеет другую сигнатуру.

Вам уже придется писать

```
struct C
{
    friend A::A( int, int );
};
```

а это может быть не тем, что вы хотели бы получить. То есть если вы, например,  хотели, чтобы другом был конструктор, который вызывается исключительно без аргументов.

То есть, опять-таки, когда имеются отдельные конструкторы, то ваши возможности более широкие.

Если рассматривать не конструкторы, а функции, то разница имеется еще более существенная.

Аргументы по умолчанию не влияют на тип функции. Поэтому, например, если вы объявили функцию как

```
void f( int, int = 0 );
```

то, несмотря на аргумент по умолчанию и того факта, что вы можете ее вызывать как

```
f( value );
```

тем не менее ее тип `void( int, int )`. А это в свою очередь означает, что вы не можете, например, написать

```
void h( void f( int ) )
{
    f( 10 );
}

void f( int x, int y = 0 ) { std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl; } 

//

h( f );
```

так как параметр функции `h` имеет тип `void( int )`., а у функции, используемой в качестве аргумента, тип `void( int, int )`

Если же вы объявите две функции вместо одной

```
void h( void f( int ) )
{
    f( 10 );
}

void f( int x ) { std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl; } 
void f( int x, int y ) { std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl; }
```

то данный вызов

```
h( f );
```

будет корректным, так как имеется функция с одним параметром.

Comment: а если поставить explicit при каждом конструкторе в 1 случае?

Comment: +1, не знал, что explicit действует на конструктор со списком.

Comment: @dragonsballZ Не могу сходу сказать. Требуется время, чтобы сосредоточиться.:) Если что-то придет в голову, то дополню свой ответ.

Comment: @dragonsballZ Если рассматривать не конструкторы, а перегруженные функции, то это имеет значение, так как при определении типа функции параметры по умолчанию не влияют на тип функции. То есть если вы объявите, например, void f( int ) и void f( int, int = 0 ), то это будут два различных типа, что может привести к невозможности использования одной из функций, например, в шаблонах или с классом std::function. ,

Comment: @dragonsballZ Я дополнил свой ответ.:)

Answer (score 0):

Различия уже объяснил @Vlad from Moscow, я лишь предложу, из двух вариантов в вопросе, третий вариант:

```
class A
{
  public:
   A():A(0, 0) {}
   explicit A(int x): A(x, 0) {}
   A(int x, int y): a{x}, b{y} {}
  private:
   int a,b;
};
```

На мой взгляд именно этот вариант является лучшим, т.к. он имеет явный конструктор с одним аргументом, что является хорошей практикой и уберегает от некоторых ошибок. С другой стороны, `explicit` для конструкторов, у которых больше или меньше одного аргумента, на мой взгляд, является лишним. Т.к. случайно создать объект из более чем одного аргумента проблематично, а именно за этим мы и приписали `explicit` у одноаргументнова конструктора — защита от случайных ошибок.

Ну и самое главное, мы имеем лишь один конструктор, который инициализирует поля. Все остальные действуют через него, что позволяет минимизировать ошибки инициализации.